# Notification of privileges that I do not have and cannot yet have

Tags: bug

I have notifications about privileges, like in the picture, but I don't have them because I still lack reputation. Just wanted to report this bug.

[image]

Comment: This answer below raises the question, should users receive a notification on the gain and the loss of privileges? I think that would bes less confusing.

Comment: @political_noob The question wouldn't be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that you had gained enough reputation for the privileges and later lost that reputation. The rep required for those are 15/15/20 and which you are missing by a single vote. I would wager that there was a vote that was later removed from your answer which dropped you below the level needed for those.

Comment: Thought I should see such reputation changes, but it doesn't seem to be the case. It's a bit confusing, but it answers my question.

Comment: @FriedrichApril If you had gotten 2 upvotes for +20 rep and one was removed before you looked it would have updated to reflect that. It doesn't do the same for privileges that you had gained but lost.

Comment: I've now seen it myself and it's exactly the same with downvotes.